# Is there an elegent way to estimate the cutoff for a kind of normal distributed vector?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector with normal distributed data centered around 0 and additionally some "noise" to the left and right. It's pretty symatrical usually. Let's say it looks somewhat like this:

```
dataVector <- c(rnorm(30,mean=-15,sd=10),rnorm(200,sd=10),rnorm(30,mean=15,sd=10))
```

[image: Density plot of my vector]
What I want to do is estimate where that center normal distribution "ends", so the cutoff line should seperate it from the rest. Looking at the density plot I can make a pretty good guess where that cutoff should roughly be:
[image: Where does the vertical line meet the x axis]

I was thinking about where the second derivate reaches 0. But I don't know the underlying kernel function or whether it actually ever is zero for my values.

How can I estimate the cutoff(dataVector)?

Comment: A normal distribution has support from negative infinity to infinity, it doesn't "end". What exactly are the requirements for this "cutoff"?

Comment: It should seperate data that belongs to the normal distribution centered around 0 from the rest.

Comment: and the normal distribution density function never reach 0, unless you define the 'end' as some threshold close to 0.

Comment: No but it second derivate would reach it, no?

Comment: The second derivative of the normal probability density function is 0 at `mu + sigma` and `mu - sigma`. (See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190066/prove-one-standard-deviation-lies-on-inflection-points) for a proof.) Not sure if that's what you're after though.